# Finding minimum excludant of a set

Tags: python, list

I am a total beginner in Python.
Can't figure out why the following doesn't work when I am trying to find the minimum excludant of the given set.

```
def mex(my_list):
    my_list = set(my_list)
    mex = 0
    while mex in my_list:
        mex += 1
    return mex

a = [1, 0, 2, 4]
print(mex(a))
```

Comment: For the visitors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mex_(mathematics)

Comment: Running your code will print `3`... is this incorrect?

Comment: It is correct. When I run it it says None

Comment: How do you run your code?

Comment: Press on green arrow in Pycharm. It says None, Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: The arrow is "Run 'main'"

Comment: I got it!!! Thanks. Was running a different file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `return` needs to be indented and you need a ":" after the while statement.

```
def mex(my_list):
    my_list = set(my_list)
    mex = 0
    while mex in my_list:
        mex += 1
    return mex

a = [1, 0, 2, 4]
print(mex(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed a colon after the while loop, just add `:` at the end.